# change month date name of arabic language in odoo

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-8, datejs

I'm working with odoo/openerp, and I changed the interface language to Arabic from `setting--> translation--> load translation` , I have a problem where the month names of `(January-February-March,etc` ) are translated to `(كانون - ايلول ,etc )`, but I need to change them in the system to  `(يناير -فبراير - مارس , etc )`. I tried to change the files in [datejs](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/web/static/lib/datejs) library in [web module](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/web) but there is no change, and I searched for the `.po` files that contain these months and edited them all with also no hope, and my last try was to change the language terms of the months, but am still not getting what I need, so could you please tell me how I can change the date months names to the required names in odoo/openerp server in either configs or code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I did to overcome this issue is to change the locale file for moment.js in addons/web/static/lib/moment/locale in which ar.js is being used. The trick is to change all Hindi characters with Arabic numerals in this file and clear the cache from the browser.